# Is there any way to make Highstock columnrange look like Highchart columnrange?

Tags: highcharts

As you can see, I have ranges of dates in highchart:

[image: Highchart columnrage]

In highstock, I do not know if I can do the same because I can't find examples in the documentation.

[image: Highstock columnrage]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want to use a specific feature from Highstock, e.g. navigator? StockChart does not support inverted chart. If you want a kind of navigator functionality, then you can look at master-detail chart example: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail

Answer (score 2):

You can get pretty much the same chart with highstock, just remove navigator and rotate chart and enable data grouping. Example below:

```
chart: {
  type: 'columnrange',
  renderTo: 'container',
  inverted: true
},
```

and

```
dataGrouping: {
  enabled: true
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/yj54ojzs/